# Download flashplugin-installer Error

Tags: 12.10, flash

I'm getting this error constantly:

```
Failure to download extra data files
The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

flashplugin-installer

The download will be attempted again later, or you can try the download again now. Running this command requires an active internet connection.
```

I've tried purging my existing flashplugin, reinstalling it using `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`, tried installing the Firefox Flash plug-in from the software center, and nothing appears to work. Currently running Lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing and using 'Google Chrome' it has flash installed already...

If Flash player doesn't work on 'Google Chrome' you have to do this:

1) If the Flash plugin is already installed for Firefox, we have to find out where it is located:

```
sudo updatedb
sudo locate libflashplayer.so
```

2) If it is installed, output should be similar to this one...

```
falko@falko-desktop:~$ sudo locate libflashplayer.so
/opt/Adobe AIR/Versions/1.0/Resources/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
falko@falko-desktop:~$
```

... which means the Flash plugin is located in /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so.

3) If there's no output, this means that the Flash plugin isn't installed - you can then install it as follows:

```
sudo aptitude install flashplugin-installer
```

4) Now we create a plugins directory for Google Chrome

```
sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

5) Now copy the Flash plugin to it:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins
```

6) Finally we have to tell the Google Chrome launcher that it should look out for plugins. To do this, we right-click on Applications and select Edit Menus:

[image: Edit Menus]

7) In the Menu Editor, go to Internet > Google Chrome and click on the Properties button:

[image: Properties Button]

8) In the Launcher Properties window, replace the contents of the Command field with this line...

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --enable-plugins %U
```

... and click on Close:

[image: Command Field]

9)Then leave the Menu Editor.

That's it! We can now launch Google Chrome (Applications > Internet > Google Chrome):

[image: Launching 'Google Chrome']

10) If you start Google Chrome for the first time, you'll see this dialogue. Make your choices and click on Start Google Chrome:

[image: 'Google Chrome' dialogue]

11) Now go to a web site that has Flash videos (e.g. YouTube), and you should be able to watch them which means that the Flash plugin is working:

[image: Testing Flash Player]

Hope this helps you and anwsers the question :-)

### **Good Luck!**

Useful Links:

1.http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ (In small text you will see **click here** on this website)

2.http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

---

Please click on the tick if this answer helped you!

Answer (score -1):

Per RNA's advice in another post:

```
 sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed
```

fixed on 14.04.

I removed this file in 12.04 LTS, did not have to re-install flashplugin.
Works now, no error message at bootup!

---

Correction: next day error message came back, tried the purge method and re-installed flashplugin, error message appeared immediately.